# Class differences in isinstance() in python3 vs python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Could someone please explain the following behaviour difference?

```
class a():
    pass
class b(a):
    pass
```

In Python2:

```
>>> isinstance(b(),type(a()))
True
>>> isinstance(a(),type(b()))
True
```

In Python3:

```
>>> isinstance(b(), type(a()))
True
>>> isinstance(a(), type(b()))
False
```

Comment: Those are *old-style classes* in Python 2.x.

Comment: Also, there is no need to `type` the instance, just use the class as such, I mean,  e.g. `isinstance(b(), a)`. There will be no differences.

Comment: OK, Thanks for the quick reply.
I'm cleaning up code for bicop as I need it to work in Py3. 
He has a test that compares the classes of the old style, how do I make that test pass? or is it just as @Kanak says there is no need for type

Comment: You can either do as I say or simply use the new-style class, i.e. `class a(object):pass`. There will be no differences neither.